# Will third party unity lenses be included in the dashboard search?

Tags: unity, lenses, unity-dash

There are already a number of lenses under development. Will the search results for these lenses be included in the main unity dashboard search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Third party lenses can control whether their results are included in the main dashboard search by ShowGlobal & ShowEntry keys in the .place file for the lens. There doesn't currently appear to be a UI option for setting this.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses#Registration for information about the .place file.